# One statement about definite integrals implying an another.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

Could anyone please explain me the following statements :

"$$\int_{0}^{\theta}g(y)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}y^{2n-1} dy=0$$ for all $\theta$ implies $$g(\theta)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}\theta^{2n-1}=0$$ for all $\theta$ by taking derivatives. This can only be zero if $g(\theta)=0$ for all $\theta$."

Comment: What part are you confued about?

Comment: @ASKASK I have extracted the part that I am not understanding and put it into  quotation mark `" "`.

Comment: You may want to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus-I. That the derivative of $\int^x_0f(t)dt=f(x)dx$

Answer (score 3):

That's the fundamental theorem of calculus. If

$$f(\theta):=\int_{0}^{\theta}g(y)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}y^{2n-1} dy=0$$

for all $\theta$, then we differentiate to get

$$\begin{split} 0 &= f'(\theta)\\
& =g(\theta)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}\theta^{2n-1}  - 2n \int_0^\theta g(y)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n+1}}y^{2n-1} dy\\
&= g(\theta)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}\theta^{2n-1} - \frac{2n}{\theta} \int_{0}^{\theta}g(y)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}y^{2n-1} dy \\
&= g(\theta)\frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}\theta^{2n-1}. 
\end{split}$$